# UiPath Activity Creator - package version not changed

Tags: c#, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I am starting out with UiPath and am at the point of creating custom activities / packages. I am using UiPaths Activity Creator.

Following a successful publish to UiPath , I would like to be able to make code changes and then re-publish. As part of this, the code changes should result in a new version, which triggers an update option in Extension Management. Is this possible?

At the moment my solution is to change the version in Visual Studio, under properties.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit xxx.xxxx.Activities.Design project's project file (on mouse right click context menu "Edit Project File"),and modify that following content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' AND '$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'">
    <PackageVersion>0.1.6.$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(MMddHHmmss))</PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <PackageVersion>0.1.6</PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
....
```

and the above 0.1.6 is what you want new publish's package version

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your answer, but it does not work as a solution

Comment: @DanielXavDeOliveira you can refer the  https://docs.uipath.com/developer/docs/package-metadata